# Аккордеон скрывает блоки не полностью

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть вот такой аккордеон http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/KxrXP/. Как сделать, чтобы блоки скрывались не полностью, а к примеру только часть, а при нажатии раскрывались полностью?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обвернуть текст еще в один `div`, высота у которого будет постоянная, а в `JS` вот так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showmore').click(function() {
        var $accord = $('.gradient1_inner');
        var $accordDiv = $accord.find('div');
        var height = $accordDiv.height();

        if(parseInt($accord.css('height'))  < height) {
            $accord.stop().animate({'height': height});
        }
        else {
            $accord.stop().animate({'height': height/2});
        }
    });
});
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/KxrXP/1/

Comment: Сделал немного по другому, но и за это спасибо!

Comment: @Karalahti пожалуйста! Я лишь хотел донести мысль!)